# If the integral of a differential form is path-independent, then is the differential form an exact differential?

Tags: calculus, integration, differential

The statement "If it is an exact differential, then its integral is integral path-independent; it only depends on the both integral path endpoints regardless of which path between them is chosen." is true as being shown in the Wikipedia page [Exact differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential) and other textbooks.

Is the converse of this statement, "If the integral of a differential form is path-independent, then it is an exact differential", also true?

Comment: Hint: let $\omega$ be such a differential, fix a point $P_0$, and consider $P \longmapsto \int_{P_0}^{P}{\omega}$.

Comment: For an answer, see [here](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/path-independent-1-forms-are-exact/) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267823/path-independence-of-integral-of-1-form-implies-the-form-is-exact).

Answer (score 1):

***Let me attempt this in two parts.***

**Part A**

On page 472 of  "Concepts in Thermal Physics" by Blundell and Blundell. We find the answer to your question.

Let me attempt to put it here in simple physics style.

Consider:  $F_1(x,y)dx + F_2(x,y)dy$
It is exact if it can be written as the differential
$ df  = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}) dx + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}) dy$

thus
$F_1(x,y) = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})$;

$F_2(x,y) = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$

thus $\mathbf{F} = \nabla f$

so $\int_{x1}^{x2} F_1(x,y) dx + F_2(x,y) dy  = \int_{x1}^{x2} \mathbf{F} \cdot dr = \int_{x1}^{x2} df  = f(x2) - f(x1) $

***The answer depends only on the initial and final states of the system***

***For an inexact differential, the initial and final state is not enough. The path must also be specified.***

***Part B***

What about a two-form?

Well, it will seem that for a 2-form, $H_2$, a subset of $R^3$

There is a one form $H_1 = f_1 dx + f_2 dy + f_3 dz$

let  $df_i=\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_1}dx_1+\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_2}dx_2+\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_3}dx_3$

Then $dH_2 = \sum_i df_i  dx_i \wedge dx_i$

This generalizes to k-form in $U \subset R^n$

Also, please see Poincare's lemma

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_lemma