# On a open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$, a differential $1$-form is exact if and only if the integral on every smooth closed curve is zero

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms

The question is basically the title. Given an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, prove that $\omega$ is an exact differential $1$-form if only if for every smooth closed curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to U $,    $\gamma\in C^\infty$
$\int_{\gamma}\omega=0$

The first implication is a mere consequence of the definition of the integral for a 1-form on a curve and the fact that $\omega=df$ where $d$ is the differential operator.
I don't really know how to prove the other implication and I could not find any hint neither from the book I am studying nor from the lessons provided by my university.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: Fix a point $P_0$, and consider the map $P \longmapsto \int_{P_0}^P{\omega}$.

Comment: First show that the integral over every piecewise-smooth curve must be $0$.

Comment: FWIW, the same question was [asked yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4393463/if-the-integral-of-a-differential-form-is-path-independent-then-is-the-differen#comment9187267_4393463).